# Nontrivial solutions for $\sum x_i = \sum x_i^3 = 0$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

For $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, let  $\{x_i\}$ be a *fundamental* solution to the equations:
$$
\sum_{i= 1}^N x_i = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^3 = 0
$$
if $x \in \{x_i\} \Rightarrow -x \notin \{x_i\}$.

For instance, a fundamental solution with $N=7$ is given by

$$
x_1 = 4, \quad  x_2 = x_3 = x_4 = -3, \quad  x_5 = x_6 = 2, \quad  x_7 = 1
$$

What is the minimum $N$ for which a fundamental solution exists?

Comment: Minor nitpick: the double use of $i$ in the line after the displayed equation really makes me wince, and the formulation looks odd: are you sure you mean to say "if $x_i$ belongs to the set $\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$, then ... " ?

Comment: I'll edit to address it, thanks. To the question you ask, yes, intended meaning is "if $x$ belongs to the set, then $-x$ does not"

Comment: The "fundamental" condition is not necessary. A minimal solution won't include both $x$ and $-x$.

Comment: not sure I understand. $\{x, -x\}$ is a solution to the system with $N=2$. That's the kind of solutions I don't want.

Comment: Then the minimum is $N=0$.

Comment: $N=4$ is not possible even over $\bf C$.  The 1st and 3rd elementary symmetric functions of the $x_i$ would vanish, so they would be roots of a polynomial $x^4 + s_2 x^2 + s_4 = 0$, and would thus split into two $\{x,-x\}$ pairs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can get $N=6$ from $1+5+5=2+3+6$, $1^3+5^3+5^3=2^3+3^3+6^3$.

We can get $N=5$ from $2+4+10=7+9$, $2^3+4^3+10^3=7^3+9^3$.

Comment: Heh, ok, waiting for that final edit where you give an $N=4$ solution or prove it is impossible.

Comment: Obviously, $N=3$ is impossible by Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: I suspect $N=4$ is impossible, if for no other reason than that I can't find an example of it in Gloden's book, Mehrgradige Gleichungen.

Comment: By looking at (x -a)^3 + (y+a)^3, one is well on the road to showing N less than 5 has no nontrivial solutions.

Comment: If $N=4$ had a solution, then both pairs of (positive) integers would have the same sum and product. Any two numbers are determined by those values, up to ordering.

Comment: @Zach, one should also consider $a^r=b^r+c^r+d^r$, $r=1,3$, with $a,b,c,d$ all positive.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That case is impossible since $a^3=(b+c+d)^3 > b^3+c^3+d^3$.

Comment: @Tony, sure, I just thought it should be mentioned. So, now you have mentioned it, and we're OK.

Comment: Thank you all. Several answers were helpful but I guess this was the one who showed an $N=5$ solution so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 14):

For $N=4$ we get the projective cubic curve
$$
x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3=(x_1+x_2+x_3)^3.
$$
But this is just the union of $x_1=-x_2$, $x_1=-x_3$, and $x_2=-x_3$, contrary to your requirements. Hence $N \geq 5$. Therefore Gerry Myerson's solution is optimal.

Another way to see that $N=5$ can be attained is as follows: for $N=5$, the equations define the smooth, projective cubic surface $X$ given by
$$
x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3+x_4^3=(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^3,
$$
called the *Clebsch surface* by some authors. Now since $X$ has a rational point, e.g. $(0:0:0:1)$, it has a Zariski dense set of them (for example by Segre--Manin), and therefore it has a rational point $(x_1:x_2:x_3:x_4)$ with all $x_i$ integral and $x_i \neq -x_j$ for $i \neq j$. (Admittedly this argument is phrased in a non-constructive way, but it is in fact easy to write down a birational parametrization of $X$, and so construct a plethora of integral solutions to the system with $N=5$.)

Answer (score 6):

Suppose there were a solution with $N=4$. Then we have the following two possible cases:

1. Three of the $x_i$ have the same sign. Then w.l.o.g. we have $x_1,x_2,x_3>0$ and $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^3=x_1^3+x_2^3+x_3^3$, which is impossible.
2. Two of the $x_i$, say $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive, and $-x_3$ and $-x_4$ are positive. Then we have
   $x_1+x_2=x_3+x_4$ and $x_1^3+x_2^3=x_3^3+x_4^3$. We can deduce from these equations that also $x_1^2+x_2^2=x_3^2+x_4^2$. Now pick $\alpha$ such that $x_3=x_1+\alpha$, $x_4=x_2-\alpha$. It follows that $2\alpha(x_1-x_2)+2\alpha^2=0$, so either $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=x_2-x_1$, but these cases are excluded.

Answer (score 3):

If $N=6$ then we have a nice identity:
$$(x_1+x_2)(x_1+x_3)(x_2+x_3)=-(x_4+x_5)(x_4+x_6)(x_5+x_6).$$
(Loo-Keng Hua used such identities in his *"Additive Theory of Prime Numbers"*.) In particular if $x_5=x_6=0$ then LHS vanishes. From this observation easily follows that $N>4$.